# Error when Attempting to Group and Alias Data

Tags: sql, apache, hive

Relatively new to SQL and have been trying to return the min, average, and max of the number of events that people attended.

Essentially, I have a table titled titled `all` which I am generating a view `events` from. The view `events` contains the columns `id` and `event` from this year. I was attempting to group the counts of events by person and give this selection the label of `event count,` but for some reason am continuously receiving a parsing error. (This is being done in HIVE.)

```
--VIEW CREATION:
CREATE VIEW events
AS
SELECT all.id, all.event
FROM all
WHERE all.year = 2016;

--ATTEMPTED CALCULATION WHICH IS FAILING
SELECT avg(event_count), min(event_count), max(event_count)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(events.event), events.id FROM events
GROUP BY events.id) AS event_count;
```

Comment: Query makes no sense . . . you are confusing column aliases and table aliases and randomly mixing in other tables.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, realized I had inadvertently put the wrong id column in the GROUP BY. Corrected, but still failing. Essentially, I'm trying to pull the "id" and "event" columns from "all," place them in a view, and then calculate the mean, average, and max after grouping by counts of "event" per person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT avg(e.event_count), min(e.event_count), max(e.event_count)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(e.event) as event_count, e.id
      FROM events e
      GROUP BY e.id
    ) e;
```

As I mention in the comment, you are confusing table aliases and column aliases.  Also, it seems strange that a field called `id` would be repeated in a table.  That seems like an awkward data structure.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I've been working from examples that used aliasing and didn't quite get the gist of it.